# discontinued urls while web scraping using rvest (R)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have built a function that takes a url & gives back the desired result after scraping the webpage. The function is mentioned below:

```
library(httr) 
library(curl) 
library(rvest) 
library(dplyr)

sd_cat <- function(url){
  cat <- curl(url, handle = new_handle("useragent" = "myua")) %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("#breadCrumbWrapper") %>%
  html_text()

x <- cat[1]

#y <- gsub(pattern = "\n", x=x, replacement = " ")

y <- gsub(pattern = "\t", x=x, replacement = " ")

y <- gsub("\\d|,|\t", x=y, replacement = "")

y <- gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", y, perl=T)

z <- gsub("\n*{2,}","",y)

z <- gsub(" {2,}",">",z)

final <- substring(z,2)

final <- substring(final,1,nchar(final)-1)

final

#sample discontinued url: "http://www.snapdeal.com//product/givenchy-xeryus-rouge-g-edt/1978028261"
#sample working url: "http://www.snapdeal.com//product/davidoff-cool-water-game-100ml/1339014133"
}
```

This function works fine using sapply on a character vector containing multiple urls, but if a single url is discontinued, the function throws

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.

I need a way to skip the discontinued urls for the function to work properly.

Answer (score 5):

A better solution is to use httr and deliberately take action if the response isn't ok:

```
library(httr) 
library(rvest) 

sd_cat <- function(url){
  r <- GET(url, user_agent("myua"))
  if (status_code(r) >= 300)
    return(NA_character_)

  r %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("#breadCrumbWrapper") %>%
    .[[1]] %>% 
    html_nodes("span") %>% 
    html_text()
}

sd_cat("http://www.snapdeal.com//product/givenchy-xeryus-rouge-g-edt/1978028261")
sd_cat("http://www.snapdeal.com//product/davidoff-cool-water-game-100ml/1339014133")
```

(I also replaced your regular expressions with better use of rvest)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try with `for`, not with `sapply`. Than you could use `tryCatch()` without any problem.

```
url <- c("first_url", "second_url")
result <- vector("list", length(url))

for(i in 1:length(url)){
    result[[i]] <- tryCatch({sd_cat(url[i])}, error=function(err) "Error 404")
}
```